# Is it possible to run a Github Actions step on first pass?

Tags: github-actions

All in the title really — porting over from Jenkins, where I would normally set notifications to trigger:

1. On each fail of `master` (i.e. every red build)
2. On first pass of `master`  (i.e. first green build, when it had been failing)

I can't see a way to achieve #2 on Github Actions. Is it possible and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, it is easy as it happens within the workflow runs. You can just leverage the workflow context, and there is builtin syntax like [`if: ${{ failure() }}`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#failure) to help you do the notification trigger.

For #2, it might be little bit tricky, as you need context cross the workflow runs. I have done anything like that yet, but I think you can [persist workflow data](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/persisting-workflow-data-using-artifacts) with `actions/upload-artifact` and `actions/download-artifact` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I have #1 working fine. Normally I'm using `upload-artifact` for results or steps within a run. [The docs you link to](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/persisting-workflow-data-using-artifacts#sharing-data-between-workflow-runs) mention that if you need to share artifacts between runs that you should push the values somewhere (e.g. S3) and use an external API to refetch them. While I know that would work, really looking for a way to do this without setting up an external system to store state if possible!

Comment: you dont have to use s3, but github package should do the work out of the box. It does have separate pricing though.

Comment: While #1 is critical and important, I don't feel the same way for #2 (which is almost nice to have feature).